# Deploy container to docker swarm with compose: publish Additional property publish is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

The following is not working, do you know why?

This is the error: publish Additional property publish is not allowed

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: golang:1.9
    working_dir: /app/src
    command: go run main.go
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/src/
    publish:
      - "8080:8080"
```

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 22:53:38 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.07.0-ce
 API version:  1.31 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   8784753
 Built:        Tue Aug 29 17:46:50 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using ports and not publish

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: golang:1.9
    working_dir: /app/src
    command: go run main.go
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/src/
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: Now I get: curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: That just means that the app is not running inside well. You should also not use go run main.go. It's ok for development but not for testing. You should compile and then use. See this for more details https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/